# HTML5 video timeupdate function not working onload

Tags: jquery, html

I'm creating a custom HTML5 video player with jQuery/CSS, and *(almost)* everything works fine.

But in Firefox, it won't show the time (current time and duration). It only shows after you have clicked on the play-button. In all other browsers, the time is shown right after the site has loaded.

**This is my code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("video").on("timeupdate", function(event) {

        var currentTime = this.currentTime;
        var duration = this.duration;

        var minutes = Math.floor(currentTime / 60);
        var seconds = Math.round(currentTime - minutes * 60);
        var tminutes = Math.floor(duration / 60);
        var tseconds = Math.round(duration - tminutes * 60);

        if(minutes < 10) { minutes = '0'+minutes; }
        if(tminutes < 10) { tminutes = '0'+tminutes; }
        if(seconds < 10) { seconds = '0'+seconds; }
        if(tseconds < 10) { tseconds = '0'+tseconds; }

        $("#current").text(minutes+':'+seconds);
        $("#duration").text(tminutes+':'+tseconds);

    });
});
```

I've tried to change `on` to `ready`m but without any luck.

I've also read somewhere that `"timeupdate"` should be `"seeked"` and `video` should be `<video preload="auto|metadata|none">` but the same result here.

And it is only in Firefox the time won't show.

Anyone who knows what to do?

I've created a very simple demo, which shows my problem:

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k5qnP/1/)

Hope that someone can help me :D

Thanks - TheYaXxE

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$("video").on("timeupdate", function(event) {...});` I used:

```
var $spc = $("video")[0],
    duration = $spc.duration,
    currentTime = $spc.currentTime;
```

..and this seems to work in all browsers including Firefox :)